# How can a ViewModel request data from a view when it needs it?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties

I have a calculated property on my View that I need to bind to my ViewModel.  I'm using WPF and it seems that there is no way to make a bindable property (Dependency Property) that is self calculating. I don't want to perform the calculations whenever the View's state changes because they are time intensive.  I want to do the calculations whenever the ViewModel needs the result, i.e. when it closes.

Comment: What kind of data does your ViewModel need from the View? ViewModels should never need to know anything about the View, so I think there might be an alternative to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Rachel, Encrypted account information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment above, I'd use a `Converter`

Your ViewModel would contain the encrypted data, and the binding to the View uses a Converter which converts it into something readable. When it's time to save the data back to the ViewModel, use the `ConvertBack` method of the converter to encrypt the data again.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding EncryptedAccountNumber, 
         Converter={StaticResource DecryptTextConverter}}" />
```

```cs
public class DecryptTextConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Implement decryption code here
        return decryptedValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Implement encryption code here
        return ecryptedValue;
    }
}
```

If the Encryption code takes a while, set your `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` and manually trigger the source update when the Save button is clicked.

Comment: I don't think I'm doing things in pure MVVM, here. I started out that way.  In rare use cases, I've designed user controls that aggregate input from the user and return the aggregated data instead of everything back to the view model.   These situations are rare, and all deal with security. This is probably the best answer so I will mark it as the answer, but it doesn't really fit my problem. *sigh*  I'm still stuck in the Windows Forms/two tier way of thinking.

Comment: Also, I have more than one fields that are encrypted (rather heavily) together.

Comment: I am a nut when it comes to customer security, `SecureStrings` all over the place (within certain modules).

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have your encryption/description in one central location that you can lock down instead of spread out throughout different UserControls?

Comment: Its not spread out.  Its a single class that gets its keys from a service module.  Its little more than interface with an encrypt / decrypt method signatures when its in the view.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.  It works the same way as `ICommand` but the view provides the delegate (`CalculationDelegate`) and the view model calls `CanExecute` and `Execute`.  Its not pure MVVM but it works.

```
public interface ICalculationProvider<TResult>
{
    event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    Func<TResult> CalculationDelegate { get; set; }

    bool CanExecute();
    TResult Execute();
    bool TryExecute(out TResult a_result);
}
```

I have marked Rachel's answer as correct, simply because what I am doing here is not pure MVVM.